# Windows Firewall на контроллере домена

Tags: windows, firewall

есть вопрос по Windows Firewall. Достаточно глупый)
Возможно ли заблокировать все белые адреса и разрешить только внутренние?

например блокировка входящих
0.0.0.1-9.255.255.255
11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255
169.255.0.0-172.15.255.255
172.32.0.0-255.255.255.255
192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255

И разрешить все для серых
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16

как это будет работать? Мультикаст для DHCP?

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ необходимо знать, как минимум, его половину. Вы спрашиваете: `как это будет работать?` Встречный вопрос: что такое `это`: версия ОС, режим работы контроллера,  функционирующие сервисы, смежные сегменты ЛВС для клиентов? Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос.